# Installers binding

Tags: binding, installation, exe, packaging

I have some installers like

- JDK
- Apache Tomcat
- MySQL
- MySQL GUI, etc.

I want to bundle all these installers together into a single `.exe` file, So that a single exe will in walk through all of the installers one by one. The result will (hopefully) make installation of many packages as painless as possible for the user.

MySQL installers were in .msi format. I converted them into .exe by using an MSI to exe converter.

I'm able to find many setup creators, but I don't think they'll do what I want. How can I bundle all of these packages together under a single installer? Is there a tool that I can use to do this?

Comment: I've made some edits to help you. Remember, avoid asking things subjectively (such as 'best' or 'good').

Comment: @TimPost, I will keep your advice in my mind.....

Answer (score 2):

I got some useful links http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software , [Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406086/single-exe-to-install-group-of-softwares-and-loading-files)