# Struts2 web application security

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, struts2, security

I have a **struts2 web application**.

I am now testing my application in LAN using tomcat after converting the project into a . war file with jsp, css, js and class files. And without java files.

But if anyone who is getting access to server can read the codes.

Is there any way to protect my codes?

Whether it can be deployed if I convert my codes into a single jar file?

Is there any tools available for securing my web application?

I have to host the project in a server at clients workspace.

Anyway I have to give access to an administrator at their office for emergency shut down or any other such cases.

There I want it to be protected.

If he is accessing my codes means it will be gone.

Can I use any software like folder lock? whether it will block tomcat from accessing the folder?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: better host it at your end and let them access only UI :) else there are all way to De-compile your code in what ever format it is.

Comment: :-) That will be expensive, which my company authority will not accept. I have already suggested this.. If its a LAN all systems in client side can access it for free.. If its via internet, they will have to pay for accessing files through net..

Comment: i am still not sure why you want this we have so many application deployed and we never want such use case

Comment: @questzen Can u give any suggessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already asked this question as it has been told that you can take some steps to prevent things but its not possible to protect that 100%

why you want to secure code and from whom??

You could obfuscate and/or encrypt your .class files, but if they're determined to get to your unobfuscated byte code, they almost certainly will.

If you want to protect you HTML and java-script code then there are tools like[closure-compiler](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/)

for details refer this thread

[how-can-we-secure-our-web-application-codes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/how-can-we-secure-our-web-application-codes)

Comment: Does any1 knows answer for this question? [Binding installers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237005/installers-binding)