# Database backup from jsp page

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, struts2, backup

I have a **struts 2 (jsp) web application with MySQL database**.

Is it possible to take **database backup from jsp/java page**?

Is it possible to **restore** in the same way?

Please give me some tutorials or tips..

My actual need is to give a access to admin to **take back up and restore it using gui itself, without accessing MySQL from server**.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you can make CRUD(Create,Read,Update,Delete) operations over a database but not sure to restore /backup via programming language within JDBC api

Comment: which database you are using.for MySQL you can use there workbench which provides a backup wizard and better user simple command lines.Else you can create CURD simple curd operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using mySQl you can do something like

```
   static int BUFFER = 10485760;      

public static String getData(String host, String port,    String user, String password, String db) throws Exception {

Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
           "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump --host="  + host + " --port=" + port + 
           " --user=" + user + " --password=" + password +
           " --compact --databases --add-drop-table --complete-insert --extended-insert " +
           "--skip-comments --skip-triggers "+ db);
InputStream in = run.getInputStream(); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
int count;
 char[] cbuf = new char[BUFFER];

while ((count = br.read(cbuf, 0, BUFFER)) != -1)
         temp.append(cbuf, 0, count);

 br.close();
 in.close();

 return temp.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
byte[] data = BackupRestore.getData("localhost", "3306",
    "root", "", "test").getBytes();     
File filedst = new File(path);
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(filedst);
dest.write(data);
}
```

But i believe until you have not any compelling/fancy reason to do this better user command line tools

You can use GUI tool being shipped with MySQL,more tested and more easy to use.

```
String path="C:/datadump/db_backup.sql"
```

make sure that path `C:/datadump` should exist or you can provide any other path of your choice.

Comment: To where this result will be stored? whether it will be in .sql format?

Comment: yup can store it in any format u like all you need to define is the path and file name

Comment: "path" you have to specify where u will store your file

Comment: sorry 4 disturbing u again, my dout was how to specify path in code?
Can u give some tips for restoring also?

Comment: Does any1 knows answer for this question? [Binding installers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237005/installers-binding)

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this, though its probably not a good idea. MySQL logical backups are SQL, and don't require any access to server internals. You can make a backup using the documented SQL interface.

- You can get the list of databases, tables, views, etc. from information_schema, or from `show tables`, etc.
- You can get the table definitions from information_schema, or `show create table`
- You can get the contents of tables using `select * from table_name`
- etc.

Of course, you risk missing something (did you remember triggers, stored procedures, user-defined-functions, …?). Even if you aren't missing anything today, you risk missing something new tomorrow, when a new MySQL version comes out.

`mysqldump` should be preferred because the MySQL authors take care of remembering to add new stuff to back up to it. You could shell out to call it; its output (by default) is SQL.

Restoring a backup is fairly straight-forward; just run the SQL statements one after another.